# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void HTTPContactsController() from the type anon

Tags: integration, error

I'm writing the below class to call an api but getting the above mentioned error

label ContactsEndPointURL is https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/

```
public class HTTPContactsController {     

public void HTTPContactsController(){
    //http request class
    HTTPRequest param = new HTTPRequest();
    param.setEndpoint(label.ContactsEndPointURL);    
    param.setMethod('GET');

    //HTTPResponse Class
    HTTP  HttpParam = new HTTP();
    HTTPResponse response  = HttpParam.send(param);
    String strResponse = response.getBody();
    system.debug('Service Response is : '+strResponse);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A method whose name matches the class' name is called a constructor. Such a method must not have a return type.

```
public HTTPContactsController(){
```

Your class would be called like this:

```
HTTPContactsController c = new HTTPContactsController();
```

Comment: I have removed void and calling the class with HTTPContactsController c = new HTTPContactsController();    but getting the same error.

Comment: @PranabSarma The problem isn't specifically with this code (after removing void). I have tested this in my developer org and it works. Perhaps this class is within another class?

Comment: I have created this class yesterday and it's not referred anywhere else. I have checked with advanced code searcher as well. :(

Comment: @PranabSarma Execute Anonymous (works): `public class HTTPContactsController { public HTTPContactsController(){ HTTPRequest param = new HTTPRequest(); param.setEndpoint('https://www.google.com/'); param.setMethod('GET'); HTTP HttpParam = new HTTP(); HTTPResponse response  = HttpParam.send(param); String strResponse = response.getBody(); system.debug('Service Response is : '+strResponse); } } HTTPContactsController c = new HTTPContactsController();`

Comment: @PranabSarma There's something about where the code is placed or where you're calling it. This code definitely works in my org. As such, there may not be sufficient code in your question to give you an appropriate answer. Can you add any additional code to your question?

Comment: There is no additional code. This is the only class and i am calling it from anonymous window in my developer console with the line of code : HTTPContactsController c = new HTTPContactsController();

Comment: @PranabSarma How are you saving the code to the server? Given what you've said so far, I can only guess that the code never actually made it to the server, or you're in the wrong org when you try to execute anonymous. There's nothing else that should be stopping this from working.

Comment: I am creating the class in developer console. File > New > Apex Class. Saved the class after writing the code. Then opening Anonymous Window to call the class. That is when the error is thrown.

Comment: @PranabSarma Does the Developer Console show the file as Modified (has a `*` after the file name)? Do you see any errors on the Errors Tab? Does the class appear in Setup > Develop > Apex Classes? Does it contain the same source there as it does in the Developer Console? Does your execute anonymous window have any extra code in it? Is any of the text highlighted in the Execute Anonymous window (this may cause only part of the code to execute)?

Comment: There is no * after the file name. The class appears in Apex Classes in Set up. Same code as in developer console. No extra code in anonymous window just HTTPContactsController c= HTTPContactsController();. No highlighted text.

Comment: Is this any environment issue? Specific to my developer org?

Comment: @PranabSarma It's not specific to being *a* DE (this code runs fine in my DE), and might even occur in other types of orgs (e.g. sandboxes). Try using "compile all classes" in Setup > Develop > Apex Classes. Other than that, try deleting the class and creating it anew. Also, check the class' security. I kind of doubt that would be the cause, but it's worth adding the profile to it and see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Please Register your "url" address in RemoteSite settings

Please check below code it worked for me!!

```
 public class HTTPContactsController{
    public static HttpResponse makeGetCallout() {
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        // Deserializes the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
        Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        system.debug('map result values====>'+results);

        List<Object> contactsList= (List<Object>) results.get('contacts');


        for (Object o: contactsList) {
            system.debug('value>>>>'+o);//logic based on your requirement
        }
    }
    return response;
}}
```

If you want to review the output in anonymous window (control+E) call the method

```
              HTTPContactsController.makeGetCallout();
```

Please visits trailhead Module for better Understanding:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_rest_callouts

Comment: I have replaced my code with yours but getting the same error. I already have the URL registered in Remote site settings. Seems like there is some environment issue. I'm not able to figure it out.